# Sorting array - Can anyone help me where I'm failing?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to organize an array and I'm getting an OutOfBoundException error:

```
int[] A = {8, 6, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 4, 10, 3};
int start = 0;
int end = A.length;
public void insertionSort(int[] A, int start, int end) {
  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j > start; j--){
      if(A[j] < A[j-1]){
        int k = j-1;
        swap(A, j, k);
```

That swap function is a method already made by someone else, and he is the professor so the error isn't coming from there. Can anyone point out where I'm failing?

Comment: You have to provide more Information. Is swap throwing the error or the if-case? If swap causes the problem, check the implementation or ask the guy who wrote it. If it's the if case, your start or end variable is wrong.

Comment: Looks like an off by one error, I didn't really think about it but are you sure "i<=end" is correct? usually it would be "i<end" if "end" is the array length

Comment: And I think it should be `j=i` and not `j=i+1` in the second loop.

Comment: Thank you Phillipp, I changed it and is still failing.

Comment: I think you need to make one of the changes Philipp and dan suggested. My guess is that you don't have a whole lot of experience with debugging, and that's what this assignment is probably supposed to help you with. Add some `System.out.println(...)` statements in there and you'll probably see the problem. If you need more help, message me directly and I'll try to walk you through it.

Comment: The upper limit of i is i <= i.length. This is already 1 over the array limit. Then j starts at i+1.

Answer (score 0):

An array starts at Index 0 rather than 1. So the length of your array is already out of bounds as an index. Just change your first for loop so it runs as long as `i<end` should fix your problem.

```java
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
```

Besides that, your inner loop is also wrong. You can choose if you want to test the next Index (i+1) or the previous Index (i-1). In case of (i+1) the outer loop runs too far again (now it must be `i < end-1`). If you want to change with the previous Index (i-1), your i must start at 1 rather than 0.

For example (to swap with the next Element):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < end-1; i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j > 0; j--){
        if(A[j] < A[j-1]){
```

Comment: is this what you mean?

for (int i = start+1; i < end-1; i++){

Comment: No, now you mixed both approaches. I added Code to make it clear.

Comment: thank you very much! I appreciate your help. I'll submit it and hope it's fixed.

Comment: Still failing.. I'll ask my professor again but he wants me to figure it out on my own :(

Comment: It still doesnt sort your array though. But that's probably for another question. Please mark the answer as correct (and upvote) if it fixes your error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have faced starts with the following line:

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
```

The reason is obvious from the next line of code:

```
for (int j = i+1; j > start; j--)
```

In this line, you are initializing `j` with `i + 1` and then trying to access `A[j]` in the next line.

When `i` will become equal to `end` (because you have written the termination condition as `i <= end`), `j` will be equal to `end + 1` i.e. in the case of your array, `j` will be equal to `10 + 1 = 11`. However, the last index in `A[]` is `9` as you must already be aware that the index of an array starts at `0`. Whenever you try to access an element of an array from an index beyond the last index, the [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown.

Given below is the corrected code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = { 8, 6, 7, 9, 4, 8, 1, 4, 10, 3 };
        int start = 0;
        int end = A.length;
        insertionSort(A, start, end);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    }

    static void insertionSort(int[] A, int start, int end) {
        for (int i = start; i < end - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j > start; j--) {
                if (A[j] < A[j - 1]) {
                    int k = j - 1;
                    swap(A, j, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close and as I see it you only made one mistake.

Here is your code.

```
public void insertionSort(int[] A, int start, int end) {
   for (int j = i+1; j > start; j--){
      if(A[j] < A[j-1]){
         int k = j-1;
         swap(A, j, k);
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is with the outer `for` loop.

Change it from

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = start; i < end-1; i++)
```

The reasons are as follows:

- `i <= end` will include the `end` value, but since arrays as `0` based you will go beyond the array size.
- Also, since the inner loop add `1` to `i`, you need to do `end-1` so that `i` won't also exceed the array size.